# 01-netcfg.yaml file is not showing inside /etc/netplan after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04

I need to configure static IP under Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS i.e. Desktop version but I could not find `01-netcfg.yaml` file inside `/etc/netplan`. What could be the solution if yml file does not exist?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

```
$ ls -al /etc/netplan
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Dec 25 14:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 149 root root 12288 Dec 26 11:17 ..
```

Also inside Network Settings I do not see anything.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A search on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=cosmic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=01-netcfg.yaml) shows that NO package provides this file.

`/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` describes YOUR particular network configuration, and, as such, is a file that you have to create.

Begin by reading `man -a netplan`