# Setting just the nameserver on a tunneled nework device

Tags: networking, dns, 21.04, easytether

I'm using EasyTether to tunnel network traffic over USB through my phone. It works great.

```
$ ifconfig tun-easytether
tun-easytether: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.117.0  netmask 255.255.255.254  destination 192.168.117.1
        inet6 fe80::f476:bf20:ab51:d533  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 154278  bytes 156290109 (156.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 93661  bytes 13448935 (13.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I would like to set the nameserver on that interface to Google's public `8.8.8.8`/`8.8.4.4`.

After looking through various [how-to's on google](https://www.linux.com/topic/distributions/how-use-netplan-network-configuration-tool-linux/) it seems that I need to configure netplan.

The guides reference a yaml file at `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`. This file doesn't exist for me. [Another AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105518/01-netcfg-yaml-file-is-not-showing-inside-etc-netplan-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-1) indicated that this file needs to be created by the user (me).

The man page shows some examples of this yaml file, but the use cases don't match mine, so I feel dubious about guessing.

If all I want to do is set the nameserver on this interface, is there a simple bit of yaml I can put in that file that achieves my goal?

My guess would be this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    tun-easytether:
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

But I really really have no idea what I'm doing in that file, so I'm hoping I can find some guidance or a guide that specifically addresses my use case.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu Desktop or Server? Do you have a network connection profile (normally refers to eth0 or wlan0, or similar) that refers to tun-easytether?

Comment: Desktop, I see network profiles for wired and wifi, but tun-easytether is created by launching EasyTether from the command line. So I assume I have to manually configure these settings.